# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot open database "SIS.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SIS.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5     [book_name]      ,[book_link]      ,[user_id] FROM library", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: your connectionstring is also invalid. Initial Catalog is the name of the database - not the filename.

Answer (score 0):

The database probably requires a username and password.  The error message tells it all.